# Display AboutBox.cs from MainWindow's About_Click MenuItem

Tags: c#, wpf

Probably a very simple solution to this, but this is the first time using a WPF. I want to click on my MenuItem called "About" from MainWindow's About_Click event and it open my AboutBox.cs form. This is what I have:

.xaml

```
<MenuItem Header="About" Name="About" Click="About_Click"/>
```

.cs

```
private void About_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //This is not in the XAML code.
    }
```

Apparently AboutBox.ShowDialog; isn't wanted. I know ShowDialog will not open a Class, but I am not sure how to open a Class that is defined as a Form.

Comment: Create a new AboutBox, then ShowDialog?

Comment: As @GabrielGM said, try this: `AboutBox ab = new AboutBox(); ab.ShowDialog();`. This is assuming you have the form designer coded correctly.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something I went dumb about,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myAboutBox = new AboutBox();
myAboutBox.ShowDialog();
```